# Проблемы с авторизацией VkNet

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vknet

Сегодня начались проблемы с авторизацией, ранее всё работало, в чём причина ?

Данные для авторизации все верные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD: Видимо у ВК были какие то проблемы, всё само по себе заработало.**

Comment: посмотрите через Fiddler, что там происходит

Comment: **Исключения:** _VkApiAuthorizationException_ - неправильный логин или пароль. Другими словами - Я бы на вашем месте проверил бы данные для входа. [Официальная документация](https://vknet.github.io/vk/authorize/)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ они действительно верные - именно по ним я без проблем авторизуюсь в ручную и а ранее всегда работало без проблем - там тупо ручками вписанные данные и изменяться не могут - может что то поменялось в Api у ВК - а я просто не могу разобраться(